# $N$ balls and $M$ boxes, probability of last $ i$ boxes are empty

Tags: probability-distributions

I encountered this problem. There are $M$ boxes and $N$ balls. Balls are thrown to the boxes randomly with probability of $\frac1M$. The boxes are numbered $1, 2, 3, ..., M$.
what is the probability of last $i$ slots are empty, $i = 1, 2, 3, ...,M-1$?

I appreciate any insight on the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are $M^N$ functions from the set of balls to the set of boxes, all equally likely. The number of functions that miss $i$ **specific** boxes is $(M-i)^N$.

Equivalently, the probability that the first ball misses $i$ specified boxes is $\frac{M-i}{M}$. By independence, the probability they all do is $\left(\frac{M-i}{M}\right)^N$.

Comment: Thank you Andre Nicolas.
I have further question, when the probability is not uniform ( $1/M$). i.e. probability of throwing the balls to box 1,2,..., $M$ are $p_1$ , $p_2$,..., $p_M$, respectively.

Comment: In that case, the probability the **last** $i$ are empty is $(p_1+p_2+\cdots+p_{M-i})^N$.